# ElasticSearch 8 errors with Action/metadata line [1] contains an unknown parameter [_type] status:400

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I am trying to setup EFK (ElasticSearch 8, FluentD and Kibana) stack on K8S cluster (on-premises)

I followed this [link](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/elasticsearch-helm-chart) to install elasticsearch and installed it using helm charts and  followed this [link](https://medium.com/kubernetes-tutorials/cluster-level-logging-in-kubernetes-with-fluentd-e59aa2b6093a) to install fluentd

**Output of fluentd and elasticsearch pods**

```
[root@ctrl01 ~]#  kubectl get pods
NAME                                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
elasticsearch-master-0                                   1/1     Running   0          136m

[root@ctrl01 ~]#  kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                                                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
fluentd-cnb7p                                                   1/1     Running   0          107m
fluentd-dbxjk                                                   1/1     Running   0          107m
```

However, elasticsearch log was piled up with the following warning messages

```
2021-10-18 12:13:12 +0000 [warn]: temporarily failed to flush the buffer. next_retry=2021-10-18 12:13:42 +0000 error_class="Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest" error="[400] {\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"Action/metadata line [1] contains an unknown parameter [_type]\"}],\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"Action/metadata line [1] contains an unknown parameter [_type]\"},\"status\":400}" plugin_id="out_es"
2021-10-18 12:13:12 +0000 [warn]: suppressed same stacktrace
```

**Conf file (tailored output)**

```
2021-10-18 12:09:10 +0000 [info]: using configuration file: <ROOT>
  <match fluent.**>
    @type null
  </match>
  <source>
    @type tail
    @id in_tail_container_logs
    path /var/log/containers/*.log
    pos_file /var/log/fluentd-containers.log.pos
    tag kubernetes.*
    read_from_head true
    format json
    time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
  </source>
  <source>
    @type tail
    @id in_tail_minion
    path /var/log/salt/minion
    pos_file /var/log/fluentd-salt.pos
    tag salt
    format /^(?<time>[^ ]* [^ ,]*)[^\[]*\[[^\]]*\]\[(?<severity>[^ \]]*) *\] (?<message>.*)$/
    time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
  </source>
```

I am not sure which `'type'` field it refers to.  I am unable to find an example of ElasticSearch 8 for `match` and `source` directives to compare

It seems `type` field is **not** supported from ES 8 onwards but I am not sure on that.  Kindly let me know the reason for the error

Comment: Using `type` in request was deprecated in version 7.X and removed in version 8.X, you can read more in this [documentation link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html#_schedule_for_removal_of_mapping_types). Also, Elasticsearch 8 is still in Alpha, a lot of things may not work with it yet.

Comment: @leandrojmp Can you suggest me how to change the conf file ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I do not use fluentd, you should check their [documentation](https://docs.fluentd.org/output/elasticsearch). But again, Elasticsearch 8 is in alpha, you should stay with version 7 unless you need to test if your applications will work with version 8.

Comment: the anslike,update you fluent.conf set
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71420088/4234116

Answer (score 12):

I faced similar errors when I tried to use elasticsearch 8.2.3 with fluentBit 1.9.5. I could see elastic was sending logs but could not see any data in kibana webpage due to which could not create indices and saw the above error in fluent-bit pod logs. I followed [this github issue](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/issues/5138) and added **Suppress_Type_Name On** under outputs: section in my fluent-bit helm chart values.yaml file and it worked fine after that.

```
      [OUTPUT]
          Name  es
          Match *
          Host  {{ .Values.global.backend.es.host }}
          Port  {{ .Values.global.backend.es.port }}
          Logstash_Format Off
          Retry_Limit False
          Type  _doc
          Time_Key @timestamp
          Replace_Dots On
          Suppress_Type_Name On
          Index {{ .Values.global.backend.es.index }}
      {{ .Values.extraEntries.output }}
```

Comment: what is the consequence of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

I was working on the same issue for a few days and I found a solution but just a workaround, not the optimal solution.

**If you set `TypeName` as null for `ElasticsearchSinkOptions`, you don't face this issue.**

Unfortunately, you can't set it from appsettings.json. At least I couldn't find a way.

In background, `Serilog.Sinks.ElasticSearch` library use this property as `_type` in HTTP header. But the '_type' header,
as [leandrojmp pointed out in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69617608/elasticsearch-8-errors-with-action-metadata-line-1-contains-an-unknown-paramet#comment123052839_69617608), it is no longer available in version 8.2 of ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 2):

FluentD (and Fluent Bit) Elasticsearch output plugin puts a `_type` field in logs when transferring them to Elasticsearch. However, this field was a special field of Elasticsearch and it was removed from Elasticsearch in version 8.

Therefore, if your Elasticsearch installation has a version of 8 or later, you need to suppress FluentD (or Fluent Bit) to not put the `_type` field in logs by setting `Suppress_Type_Name` configuration parameter as `On` (default is `Off`).

```
[OUTPUT]
    Name  es
    Host  192.168.2.3
    Port  9200
    ...
    ... (other es output plugin parameters)
    ...
    Suppress_Type_Name On
```

By using this configuration parameter, FluentD (or Fluent Bit) will not include a `_type` field in the final log and Elasticsearch will not complain.

**Reference:**

https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/outputs/elasticsearch#action-metadata-contains-an-unknown-parameter-type